# Small, unpredictable results in runs of a deterministic model

Tags: floating-point, precision, computer-arithmetic

I have a sizable model (~5000 lines) written in C. It is a serial program, with no random number generation anywhere. It makes use of the FFTW library for functions using FFT - I do not know the details of the FFTW implementation , but I assume the functions therein are deterministic also (correct me if I'm in err).

The issue I cannot understand is that I am getting small differences in the results for identical runs on the same machine (same compiler, same libraries).

I use double-precision variables, and to output the result in variable `value` for example, I issue:
`fprintf(outFID, "%.15e\n", value);` or
`fwrite(&value, 1, sizeof(double), outFID);`

And I would constantly get differences such as:
2.07843469652206**4**e-16 vs. 2.07843469652206**3**e-16

I have spent much time trying to figure out why this is. I initially thought one of my memory chips have gone bad, and I've ordered and replaced them, to no avail. I subsequently also tried running my code on a colleague's Linux machine, and I get differences of the same nature.

What could be causing this? It is a small issue now, but I wonder if it is the "tip of the iceberg" (of a serious problem).

I thought I would post here instead of StackOverflow in case someone working with numerical models might have come across this issue. If anyone can shed light on this, I'd be much obliged.

**Followup to comments:**
Christian Clason and Vikram: first, thank you for your attention to my question. The articles you linked to suggest that: 1. rounding errors limits the accuracy, and 2. different code (such as introducing seemingly harmless print statements) can affect the results up to the machine epsilon. I should clarify that I am not comparing the effects `fwrite` and `fprintf` functions. I am using one OR the other. In particular, the *same* executable is used for both runs. I am simply stating the issue occurs whether I use `fprintf` OR `fwrite`.

So the code path (and executable) is the same, and the hardware is the same. With all these external factors held constant, where does the randomness come from, fundamentally? I suspected the bit flip happened due to faulty memory not retaining a bit correctly, which is why I replaced the memory chips, but that doesn't seem to be the issue here, I verified and you indicated. My program outputs thousands of these double precision numbers in a single run, and there are always a random handful that have random bit flips.

Followup to Christian Clason's first comment: Why is $2\cdot 10^{-16}$ the same as 0 within machine precision? The smallest positive number for a double is 2.22e-308, so shouldn't that be equal to 0? My program outputs thousands of values in the 10^-16 range (ranging from 1e-15 to 8e-17) and we've been seeing meaningful variations in our research project, so I'm hope we've not been looking at nonsensical numbers.

**Followup #2**:
This is a plot of the time series output by the model, to aid in the offshoot discussion in the comments.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE! Are you aware that floating point numbers have limited accuracy -- in particular, that in double precision, $2\cdot 10^{-16}$ is equal to zero up to machine precision? So the differences you report are not really meaningful, and are likely due to slight differences in the implementations of the two functions you name leading to slightly different machine code.

Comment: You are asking why your machine is not more accurate than machine precision. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon

Comment: See https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/gander/Heisenberg/paper.html for a related example of the subtle influence of code paths on floating point arithmetic. And, of course, https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/02Numerics/Double/paper.pdf

Comment: Note the 80 bit extended precision is no longer an issue- In the 64 bit Intel architecture the 80x87 instructions are no longer used.

Comment: Vikram and Christian Clason, my response became rather long so I posted an edit to my post - would you take a look? Brian Borchers, I was responding to the earlier comments and just saw your answer - I will look through it now. Thank you.

Comment: @boxofchalk1 The smallest representable number is not the same as machine precision. As soon as you do any meaningful numerical computation (not just adding two numbers), the latter is the limiting factor. If you need to reliably discern numbers of the order of $10^{-17}$ from $0$, you have to use much higher precision (quad, or [arbitrary precision](https://gmplib.org)).

Comment: @BrianBorchers Which the [page that links to this document](https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/gander/) explicitly states. I just thought that it was a neat anecdote to illustrate that you shouldn't assume computer arithmetic behaves like real arithmetic.

Comment: @boxofchalk1 To be specific (since you do not seem to be familiar with floating point arithmetic), 2e-16 is not the *same* as zero, but slightly smaller than the smallest number $u$ for which $1+u$ is not equal to $1$. (The problem is one of *relative* accuracy, not absolute accuracy, which is determined by rounding errors, not representability. Note that the two numbers you give could be different roundings of the same higher precision number.) The upshot is that for any numerical computation in double precision, a result of 2e-16 is as close to zero as you're likely to get.

Comment: @ChristianClason For a deterministic reproducible computation (which is what the OP is after) you *would* expect to get a difference between identical runs of exactly zero, not just $O(u)$.

Comment: @Kirill I know, but Brian Borchers has already explained why a deterministic code might not have completely reproducible computation. I was merely addressing the secondary point about the meaninglessness of assigning relevance to the difference between 1e-16 and 1e-17. (Hence comments, not an answer.)

Comment: @ChristianClason About your secondary point (which I realize is deviating from my original question), I've attached a plot of the model output (voltage) vs. time. So you're saying the "peaks" in the modelled voltages, which have a dynamic range of about 1e-16, may not be real? These variations are certainly expected; the modelled peaks correlate with measurements very well. Several other collaborators are also using this model. (Most of the code originate from another group and I'm not at liberty to post the entire source code - at least not without asking first.)

Comment: It might well be that the scaling of your problem is such that correct answers are on the order of $10^{-16}$.  In any case you should be concerened with the relative accuracy of your solutions.

Comment: @boxofchalk1 They certainly don't look like noise; as Brian said, if *all* your data is of that order of magnitude, you might be fine (again, it's about *relative* accuracy). To make sure, you could either rescale your problem to be of order $1$, or rerun your code with extended precision (see http://www.fftw.org/doc/Precision.html).

Comment: This makes sense to me now. Thanks, Christian Clason and Brian Borchers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are aspects of modern computing systems that are inherently non-deterministic that can cause these kinds of differences.  As long as the differences are very small in comparison with the required accuracy of your solutions, there probably isn't any reason to worry about this.

An example of what can go wrong based on my own experience.  Consider the problem of computing the dot product of two vectors x and y.

$d=\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}y_{i}$

Computing this dot product requires computing the products $x_{i}y_{i}$ and then adding up the results.  The floating point multiplications should produce precisely the same results every time.  If the floating point additions are computed in the same order each time then the sum should be identical.  However, since floating point addition is not associative, you might get different results if the product of two vectors is computed in such a way that the additions are performed in different order.

For example, you might compute the product of two vectors first as

$d=((x_{1}y_{1})+(x_{2}y_{2}))+(x_{3}y_{3})$

and then as

$d=(x_{1}y_{1})+((x_{2}y_{2})+(x_{3}y_{3}))$.

How might this happen?  Here are two possibilities.

1. Multithreaded computations on parallel cores.  Modern computers typically have 2, 4, 8, or even more processor cores that can work in parallel.  If your code is using parallel threads to compute a dot product on multiple processors, then any random perturbation of the system (e.g. the user moved his mouse and one of the processor cores has to process that mouse movement before returning to the dot product) could result in a change in the order of the additions.
2. ALignment of data and vector instructions.  Modern Intel processors have a special set of instructions that can operate on (for example) for floating point numbers at a time.  These vector instructions work best if the data is aligned on 16 byte boundaries.  Typically, a dot product loop would break the data up into sections of 16 bytes (4 floats at a time.)  If you rerun the code a second time the data might be aligned differently with the 16 byte blocks of memory so that the additions are performed in a different order, resulting in a different answer.

You can address point 1 by making your code run as a single thread and disabling all parallel processing.  You can address point 2 by requiring memory allocation to align blocks of memory (typcially you'd do this by compiling the code with a switch such as -align.)  If your code is still giving results that vary then there are other possibilities to look at.

This [documentation from Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/getting-reproducible-results-with-intel-mkl) discusses issues that can lead to non reproducibility of results with the Intel Math Kernel Library.  [Another document](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/consistency-of-floating-point-results-using-the-intel-compiler) from Intel that discusses compiler switches to use with Intel's compilers.

Comment: I see that you think your code is running single threaded.  Although you probably know your code well, I wouldn't be surprised if you were calling subroutines (e.g BLAS routines) that run multithreaded.  You should check to see exactly what libraries you're using.  You can also use system monitoring tools to see your CPU usage.

Comment: or, as stated, the FFTW library...

Comment: @BrianBorchers, thank you. The example of randomness arriving from the non-associative nature of floating point addition is enlightening. Christian Clason brought up a secondary issue about whether my model output are meaningful, given the magnitude of the numbers - it could be a major issue if he's right (and I'm understanding him correctly), so I'm looking into that now.

Answer (score 3):

[The mentioned FFTW library might run in a non-deterministic mode.](http://www.fftw.org/faq/section3.html#nondeterministic)

If you're using FFTW_MEASURE or FFTW_PATIENT mode, the programs checks at runtime, which parameter values work the quickest and then will use those parameters throughout the whole program. Because the run time will obviously fluctuate a bit, the parameters will be different and the result of the Fourier transforms will be non-deterministic. If you want deterministic FFTW, use the mode FFTW_ESTIMATE.

Answer (score 1):

While it's true that expression term evaluation order changes may very well occur due to multi-core/multi-thread processing scenarios, don't forget that there may be (even though it's a long shot) some kind of hardware design flaw at work.
Remember the Pentium FDIV problem?  (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_FDIV_bug ).
Some time ago, I worked on pc-based analog circuit simulation sofware.   Part of our methodology involved developing regression-test suites, which we would run against nightly builds of the software.   With many of the models we developed, iterative methods (e.g. Newton-Raphson (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) and Runge-Kutta) were used extensively in the simulation algorithms.  With analog devices, it is often the case that internal artifacts, such as voltages, currents, etc., occur having extremely small numeric values.  These values, as part of the simulation process, are incrementally varied over (simulated) time.  The magnitude of these changes may be extremely small, and what we often observed was that subsequent FPU operations on such delta values bordered on the "noise" threshold of the FPU's precision (64-bit floating has a 53-bit mantissa, IIRC).  That, coupled with the fact that we often had to introduce "PrintF" logging code into models to allow debugging (ah, the good ol' days!), practically guaranteed sporadic results, on a daily basis!  So, what's all this mean?   You have to expect to see differences under such circumstances, and the best thing to do is define and implement a way to decide (magnitude, frequency, trend etc) when/how to ignore them.

Comment: Thank you, Jim for the insight. Any ideas on what fundamental phenomena would cause such "internal artifacts"? I thought electromagnetic interference might be one, but then significant bits would affected too, wouldn't they?

Answer (score 1):

While floating point rounding from async operations may be the issue, I suspect that it is something more banal.  The use of uninitialized variable that is adding randomness to your otherwise deterministic code.  It is a common issue that is often overlooked by developers because when you run in debug mode all variables are initialized to 0 on declaration.  When not running in debug mode, the memory assigned to a variable has whatever value the memory had before the assignment.  The memory is not zeroed on assignment as an optimization.  If this is happening in your code, it will be easy to fix, less so in the libraries code.